# What a native speaker would say in the below case?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was at the supermarket, and the cashier asked me, “how many bags do you need?”

I was about to say, i need the number of bags enough to include all my stuff. But, unfortunately, ahe didn’t understand me. Ao i said, “i just want four.”

So, what would a native English speaker say in this case?

> - I need as many bags as enough to contain all my stuff.
> - I need a number of bags to accommodate all my stuff.
> - I need many bags to have all my stuff.

I am struggling with english for many reasons and one of them is using words what are used only in writing and, at the same time, sounds weird when are used for speaking, especially when I do communicate with English native speaker.

Comment: Are you charged for the bags? In such a case, you generally pay before the groceries are bagged. So I think this may be more of a process issue, not a language one, unless you truly believe the cashier did not understand you. Your examples should be close enough.

Comment: Yes, i am charged for the bags. @user3169

Comment: No point in making the cashier's job more difficult. I make a best guess; if I get too many I take the extras home to use on the next trip. If too low, I hand the cashier an extra dime or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A native speaker would likely say

> As many as it takes.

You can smile at this point, to let them know you're not trying to be a smart-ass.

Answer (score 2):

A native speaker would say "four" (or perhaps "four bags please").

Saying "as many bags as I need" is a *smartarse answer* and so borderline rude. Saying "as many as I need" doesn't communicate anything to the cashier. Of course you need enough bags to hold all your stuff, but how many is that?

Other *smartarse answers*

> What time is it? — Time for you to get a watch.
>
> Do you have a pencil...? — Yes, I do.  (The questioner is implicitly asking to borrow the pencil.)
>
> Where was the declaration of indendence signed? — At the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

A formally correct answer would be, "As many as are necessary to hold all my purchases." Few people would actually say that, though. As Robusto says, a native speaker would be more likely to say "as many as it takes" or "as many as are necessary" or something like that.

"I need as many bags as enough to contain all my stuff." Almost right. You could say, "I need as many bags as would be enough to contain all my stuff" or "... as many bags as are enough ...". But that's getting a little formal again.

"I need a number of bags to accommodate all my stuff." That doesn't say how many, even indirectly. "A number of" basically means more than 1 but not "many".

"I need many bags to have all my stuff." Again, this is no clue how many, beyond the vague "many".

In any case, if the cashier is asking, she doesn't want to figure out how many bags you need, she wants you to tell her. So saying "as many as needed to hold all my stuff" doesn't answer the question. She wants you to say "four" or some specific number.